# (λA)B=λ(AB)=A(λB)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are matrices and $λ$ is a scalar.

How do I prove $(λA)B=λ(AB)=A(λB) $?

I've proven the following laws with sigma notation:

1) $A + B = B + A $

2) $(A + B)C = AC + BC$

3) $C(A + B) = CA + CB $

4) $(AB)C = A(BC) $

And I'm not sure how to proceed with the scalar identity.

Comment: $\lambda A = \text{diag}(\lambda) A = A \text{diag}(\lambda)$ where $\text{diag}(\lambda)$ is the matrix with $\lambda$ on the diagonal and $0$ anywhere else.

Comment: @Riquelme $\lambda A = \lambda (\mathbb{1} A) = (\lambda \mathbb{1}) A = \text{diag}(\lambda) A$, where $\mathbb{1}$ is the identity matrix

Comment: You can prove each equality by showing that the $i,j$ entry of both sides are equal. Try and write the $i,j$ entry of each side in terms of $\lambda$ and the entries of $A$ and $B$, using the definition of scalar multiplication and matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Prove that $\lambda * M = \Lambda M$, where $\Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda)$ is the matrix with $\lambda$ on the diagonal and $0$ everywhere else, the product on the left is the scalar-matrix product and the product on the right is the usual product between matrices;
- prove that $\Lambda M=M\Lambda$ (diagonal matrices of this kind commute with all matrices).

Then $(\lambda A)B = (\Lambda A)B = \Lambda (AB) = \lambda (AB)$ and $(\lambda A)B = (\Lambda A)B  = (A \Lambda) B = A (\Lambda B) = A (\lambda B)$.